# Test CCSN Sample Code

Tags: java, ocr, simulator

I want to develop a java application for scanning and parsing (OCR) documents.
I have downloaded sample code from [here](http://www.id-reader.com/Support/Sample_Codes/). But My canon scanner is not working with the sample code.Have anyone know about any **simulators** or **virtual scanners** for testing the **CSSN OCR SDK**. (application or online services)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You didn't mention your use case, I wanted to make sure you're aware that CSSN is a specialized OCR for "structured" card-type documents such as driver's licenses, medical insurance cards, etc.

Let's take the issues one by one:

#### Java support

Of the modules making up the CSSN SDK, there is full Java support for these:

1. ID Card Scan
2. ID Card Barcode
3. Passports
4. Medical Card Scan
5. Check Scan
6. Magnetic Stripe Reader

   - The API for (1), (2), and (3) is documented here: http://id-reader.com/ftp/applications/sdk/docs/SDK_Java_API.pdf.
   - The API for Medical Card Scan (4) is covered here: http://id-reader.com/ftp/applications/sdk/docs/MedicSDK_Java_API.pdf
   - For (5) and (6), there is no documentation yet, only sample code, at the location you mentioned.

#### Canon (and other) scanners

The CSSN SDK comes bundled and works seamlessly with the ScanShell and SnapShell scanners (read more here:http://www.card-reader.com/id_scanners.htm).
However, the CSSN SDK will work with practically any scanner, your Canon included.

This is what you do to get it to work:

1. Submit the Developer Contact Form here: https://store.card-reader.com/leadform.aspx. *Make sure you mention the scanner type you are working with* (Canon, in your case).
2. Two things happen next:

   - An automated email is sent back to you containing a 60-day free trial SDK demo key.
   - Support will follow up with a separate call (they commit to respond within one work day) and provide the activation key you need.
3. Install the SDK, following the instructions here: http://id-reader.com/Support/Installation_Guides/CSSNSDKInstallationGuide.pdf

   In Screen 6, you unselect the "I don't have Activation Key" check-box, then type in the activation key you received and proceed to the end of the installation process.
4. When initializing the library you require (see **Java support**, above), you pass in the SDK demo key to the relevant `Init*()` function.
   For example, to initialize the Barcode library, call the `InitBCLib()` function, which takes a single parameter, `license`, of type `String`.

HTH. Feel free to ask any more questions you may have.